# What does a name after a question represent?

Tags: support

I was under the impression that the name that appears on a question line is the name of the last person who either supplied a solution or made a comment on it.  However, (at least) for the question  "Should high-rep users hang back a little?" this not the case.  I failed to find "Axel Sommerfeldt"s comment or answer. (See attached figure.)  Perhaps, I do not know what the name that appears at the end of a question supposed to mean?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the last person to answer or edit. In the case you point to, Axel answered then deleted his answer. Only users with reputation over 10k can see deleted material. So for example I can see his answer, and thus understand what's going on, while most people cannot.

Answer (score 16):

To add to @Joseph's answer, comments are excluded from this displayed name. Additionally, the displayed name may change depending on the view. For example, when viewing the "[**Top Questions**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/)", you will see the last answered/edited user:

[image]

However, when viewing "[**All Questions**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest)" (sorted by "newest") the user who asked the question will be displayed:

[image]

In the last view, it is clearly marked as being "asked." [Sorting by "active"](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) shows the most recent modification.

Comment: The self-referential nature of this answer pleases me.